# Save the history of results from command Prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd

1. How do I increase the screen history view while running my sripts from command prompt?
   My buffer size is already set to "999" , I would like to increase it
2. Or else, how can I export my results history of my queries from command prompt into a file locally
   Used command -- doskey /history >> \commands.txt , 
   but it only exports my command line history, but I need to export the results of those command lines

Comment: Change your line parameter. Mine is 9,999. You need torun your commands with redirection. dir c:\*.* >>CommandOutput.txt

Comment: mine can only set to 999, does not accept more than 999, Is there any other way to set buffer size

Answer (score 0):

This is where the settings are stored

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
```

Other places cmd settings are stored

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

Comment: Thanks David.  I am running sequence of SQL Scripts from CMD through testrunner, and store the results in CSV, but a feww of them are failing and liking to save the error message to local file/text

Comment: Normal output goes to stdout (Standard Out) but errorsgo to stdrrr. To redirect stdout to a file append to command >c:\log.txt. To log sterr to the same place as stdout append to above 2>&1